# GridGain: Generic data handling in cache

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, caching, gridgain

As I have been posted few questions earlier because we are going through extensive POC for GridGain and able to successfully bench mark GriGain performance and data manipulation abilities.

Right now one of the last task which is left in sleeves is to see how we can handle different type of data sets in a single cache.

1. Originally cache holds `Objects` against `Keys` and we can do search operations on binded Objects attributes, and its all columns are known, what if the incoming data is never known ?
2. what if we have to handle multiple types of data and don't want to lose the searching capabilities?
3. Is there any tutorial available related to such requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- You can store different types of objects in different caches.
- You can create typed cache projections, like `GridCacheProjection<MyKey, MyObject> prj = cache.projection(MyKey.class, MyObject.class)`. More information can be found here: http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/GridCacheProjection

Comment: Actually the data which would arrive from different sources will be totally unknown to the program and we might not know how many columns it would have and what data types it would carry.

I mean we  would not know how many fields would arrive from our various data sources on which we have to do `@GridCacheQuerySqlField` so that we can query on the given field...so what would be the best practice to achieve search/index abilities when we don't know how many columns/and data types will be in coming data...

Comment: @WaseemAkhtar Sounds like you need Portable Objects functionality which is released in GridGain 6.2.0 enterprise edition. Portable objects allow for dynamic data structure changes and index rebuilding on the fly.

Comment: One of our team lead contacted you on linked-in, you replied to share contacts/phone# so that your sales department can contact us. So he replied with contact details of our CEO but so far no contact has been made. Can you check on that ???